# System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'Error creating window handle.'

Tags: c#, dispose, objectdisposedexception, win32exception

My problem is:

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'Error creating window handle'.

I know I can solve this problem with `Dispose()`, but when I use it in the program, I'm displaying another error:

> System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Can not access a disposed object.
>   Object name: 'PictureBox'. '

I use the following code:

```
private void SetUpPuzzle_Click(int parts)
{
    Panel P = new Panel
    {
        Size = new Size(200, 200),
        Location = new Point(394, 62),
    };

    Controls.Add(P);
    Control board = P;
    int total = parts * parts;
    var PB = new PictureBox[total];
    var imgarray = new Image[total];
    var img = User_Image.Image;
    int W = img.Width / (int.Parse(Math.Sqrt(double.Parse(parts.ToString())).ToString()));
    int H = img.Height / (int.Parse(Math.Sqrt(double.Parse(parts.ToString())).ToString()));
    int size = 200 / (int.Parse(Math.Sqrt(double.Parse(parts.ToString())).ToString()));

    for (int x = 0; x < parts; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < parts; y++)
        {
            var index = x * parts + y;

            imgarray[index] = new Bitmap(W, H);
            using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(imgarray[index]))
                graphics.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(0, 0, W, H),
                                   new Rectangle(x * W, y * H, W, H), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

            PB[index] = new PictureBox
            {
                Name = "P" + index,
                Size = new Size(size, size),
                Location = new Point(x * size, y * size),
                Image = imgarray[index],
                SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
            };

            PB[index].MouseEnter += Images_M_E;
            PB[index].MouseLeave += Images_M_L;
            PB[index].MouseClick += Form_MouseClick;
            *PB[index].Dispose();
            *board.Controls.Add(PB[index]);
        }
    }
}
```

When I want to create 10,000 objects

This error is displayed.

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the lines these get thrown on

Comment: I do not understand what you mean

Comment: In which line get error?

Comment: In lines marked with *.

Comment: Please replace my codes and test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem is:

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'Error creating window handle'.

Indeed. You are creating **way too many controls** for a `Winforms` application.

And disposing of them doesn't really help because you can't use a disposed object any longer..

To have this kind of large puzzle (**10k** pieces) you need to change from using `PictureBoxes` (or any other `Controls`) to display the puzzle pieces to a different approach. This has been suggested in the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52139041/how-to-convert-image-to-puzzle/52139364#52139364) but then you only wanted to have **100** pieces, remember?

The most common approach is this: Keep a list of images (when they are <= 256x256 pixels do put them into an `ImageList`!) and draw them in the board's `Paint` event. This will get rid of all the overhead involved with `PictureBoxes`.

(Aside: One may think this will not be performant with all the `DrawImage` calls. But all those `PictureBoxes` also need to draw all the pixels on all their surfaces, so that is no issue. But they also have to carry the overhead of being (under the hood) fully functional `windows` (see the error message!), which is why the system can only have a limited number of them; always try to keep the number of controls **< 1k**!)

You will have to move the placement logic to the board's `Paint` event  and will also have to change the event model..:

Instead of having each `PictureBox` respond to its own events you will have to find a way to do all the work in the board's events. This will have to be diffenrent, depending on the event.

Since we don't know which event you have and what they do and which data they need for their work, it is hard to give all the necessary details, so I'll just point out a few things..:

- There will not be a `Enter` or `Leave` event you can use. Instead you need to detect entering an area of a piece by testing for it in the MouseMove event. If you keep a `List<Rectangle>` you can use `Rectangle.Contains(e.Location)` for this test.
- You can detect a MouseClick but then will have to find out which area was clicked. If your Enter and Leave logic from the MouseMove is working you can use its result to know where the Click went.

Similar ideas can be used for all other events; some are simple, some need a little calculation but they will all be fast and pretty easy to implement..

To optimize performance try to make the image n the right size and use [Format32bppPArgb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) as the pixel format, because it is faster to display.

Another option is to pull the pixel data right from the original image in the `Paint` event with the same calculations you use now to create them. (There is a `DrawImage` overlay that uses two `Rectangles`, one to determine the target and one for the source area..) This saves `GDI` handles, at least if you can't use an `ImageList`.

Always plan for growth! For a better implementation do create a `Piece` class. It should hold a `Rectangle` and an integer index into the `ImageList`'s `Images` collection. It could also have a  method `Switch(Piece otherPiece)` which would either switch the `Rectangles` or the indices.

Good luck :-)

Comment: tanx for your answer .best regard

Answer (score 1):

I met this exception because endless loop creating new UI control and set its properties. After looped many times, this excption was thrown when change control visible property. I found both User Object and GDI Object (From Task Manager) are quite large.

I guess your issue is similar reason that system resources are exhaust by those UI controls.

Answer (score 0):

I comment `PB[index].Dispose();` and it's work.

```
private void SetUpPuzzle(int parts)
        {
            // Comment ***********
            //Panel P = new Panel
            //{
            //    Size = new Size(200, 200),
            //    Location = new Point(394, 62),
            //};

            //Controls.Add(P);
            //Control board = P;     ***********
            int total = parts * parts;
            var PB = new PictureBox[total];
            var imgarray = new Image[total];
            var img = User_Image.Image;
            int W =Convert.ToInt32(img.Width / Math.Sqrt(parts));
            int H = Convert.ToInt32(img.Height / Math.Sqrt(parts));
            int size = Convert.ToInt32(200 / Math.Sqrt(parts));

            for (int x = 0; x < parts; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < parts; y++)
                {
                    var index = x * parts + y;

                    imgarray[index] = new Bitmap(W, H);
                    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(imgarray[index]))
                        graphics.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(0, 0, W, H),
                                           new Rectangle(x * W, y * H, W, H), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

                    PB[index] = new PictureBox
                    {
                        Name = "P" + index,
                        Size = new Size(size, size),
                        Location = new Point(x * size, y * size),
                        Image = imgarray[index],
                        SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
                    };

                    PB[index].MouseEnter += Form1_MouseEnter; 
                    PB[index].MouseLeave += Form1_MouseLeave; 
                    PB[index].MouseClick += Form1_MouseClick; 
                    //Comment                         
                    //PB[index].Dispose();       < -----------------
                    // Add PB in Panel in form
                    panel1.Controls.Add(PB[index]);


                }
            }
            // after add all refresh panel
            panel1.Refresh();
        }


        private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private void Form1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private void Form1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

Then Call the `SetUpPuzzle` method in your button like :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SetUpPuzzle(10);
        }
```

Comment: When I want to create 10,000 objects

This error is displayed.

Comment: I do not have problems for less than 10,000

Comment: @آرمانغروی So you're trying to create more than 10,000 controls on the UI? Then I guess you're probably running out of resources / out of available handles. Have you considered using some kind of UI virtualization?

Comment: your code not worked. System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'Error creating window handle.'